# find attributes in custom directive for methods

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have this code

```
   case 'ROLES':
            if(scope.ersProfileEditableFieldValue){
                scope.ersProfileSectionData[scope.field.code] = scope.ersProfileEditableFieldValue.map(function(val){return val.id});
            }
            scope.initRoles();
            tpl ='<div ng-if ="roles.length>0">'
                +'<ers-multi-selector  ers-options="roles" on-change="test(message)"'
                +'    is-primary-selector="true" placeholder="Enter a Role" selected-options="ersProfileSectionData[field.code]">'
                +' </ers-multi-selector></div>'
                iAttrs.$observe('onChange', function(event, value){
                    console.log("here");
                    console.log(event);
                    console.log(value);
                })
            console.log(scope);
            console.log(iElement);
            console.log(iAttrs);
            break;
```

in this **ers-multi-selector**
 custom directive i have to find **on-change** attributes which have test method how can i find that attributes so i can manupulate it.

i am showing some code of this plug-in.

```
angular.module('ersMultiSelector',[]);
angular.module('ersMultiSelector').directive('ersMultiSelector', function(){
return{
    scope: {
        ersOptions: '=',
        isPrimarySelector: '=',
        placeholder: "@",
        selectedOptions: '=',
        onChange: '&'
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true, 
    templateUrl: 'libs/planner/ers-multi-selector/template/multi-selector.html',
    controller : [function(){
        var vm  = this;
        vm.addOption = function(toselect){
            vm.onChange({"message":"i am working"});
            toselect.isused = true;
            vm.selectedOptions.push(toselect.id);
            vm.selectedOptionsVirtual.push(getVoption(toselect.id, 
                toselect.name, vm.selectedOptions.length - 1,  toselect));
            vm.selected = undefined;
        }


    }]
}
});
```

Comment: use `link` in the directives or use [`compile` which gives you `pre/post` methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-) to manipulate templates.

Comment: i want attribute value at the place of where i have defined the ers-multi-selecter plug-in

Comment: `restrict, link` these two important things are missing in your directive code.

Comment: i have add the restrict :'AE' , but how to find on-change attribute value

Comment: Do you know about `link` function of directives? That is where you can get like `link:function(scope, el, attrs){}` check the `attrs` param.

Comment: i know buddy , i have already used it in its parent directive where i would manupulate it but how to find on-change attribute

Answer (score 0):

use `link` function instead of `controller` in `custom-directive`

for more info see the link function of custom directive in the below link

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: thanks ,but this not the solution i have different scenerio